# PHP redirect based on IP location

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ip

I have a multilingual site with an 'index.php' sitting on example.com domain. This index.php should have this redirection code so when users go to 'example.com' they get redirected to either the French or English version of the site.

In its simplest form I'd like the conditional statement to read:

If IP is based in France redirect to example.com/fr else if anywhere else in the world redirect to example.com/en

How might I set this up using PHP?

Comment: do you have IP database with location?

Comment: @user1844933 No I don't. Why is this needed?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php and use a cache to store the IP address as not to make the request every time.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");

$ch = curl_init('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={the IP address, used mine for example}');

if (!$ch) {
    die('Failed CURL');
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$serverResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$serverResponse) {
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    throw new Exception('HTTP error: ' . $code);
}

die(print_r($serverResponse));
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [geoplugin_request] => My IP
    [geoplugin_status] => 206
    [geoplugin_credit] => Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href=\'http://www.maxmind.com\'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>.
    [geoplugin_city] => 
    [geoplugin_region] => 
    [geoplugin_areaCode] => 0
    [geoplugin_dmaCode] => 0
    [geoplugin_countryCode] => GB
    [geoplugin_countryName] => United Kingdom
    [geoplugin_continentCode] => EU
    [geoplugin_latitude] => 51.5
    [geoplugin_longitude] => -0.13
    [geoplugin_regionCode] => 
    [geoplugin_regionName] => 
    [geoplugin_currencyCode] => GBP
    [geoplugin_currencySymbol] => &#163;
    [geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8] => Â£
    [geoplugin_currencyConverter] => 0.6003
)
```

So use the country code.